# x-www-form-urlencoded provider for posting

Tags: android, swagger, retrofit2

I am trying to do a post using content-type x-www-form-urlencoded.
All im getting back is "A message body writer for Java type, class java.lang.String, and MIME media type, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, was not found"

The code gen did not create this call for me i hacked it together using other code and google. But in the end it seems to always want a provider like "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:$jackson_version"

```
public Token Login(String username, String password) throws ApiException
{
    Object postBody = null;

    if (username == null || username.isEmpty())
    {
        throw new ApiException(400, "Missing the required parameters 'username' when calling Login");
    }
    if (password == null || password.isEmpty())
    {
        throw new ApiException(400, "Missing the required parameters 'password' when calling Login");
    }

    // create path and map variables
    String path = "/token".replaceAll("\\{format\\}", "json");

    // query params
    List<Pair> queryParams = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    Map<String, String> headerParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, Object> formParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    formParams.put("username", username);
    formParams.put("password", password);
    formParams.put("grant_type", "password");


    final String[] accepts = {"application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"};
    final String accept = apiClient.selectHeaderAccept(accepts);

    final String[] contentTypes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"};
    final String contentType = apiClient.selectHeaderContentType(contentTypes);

    String[] authNames = new String[]{};


    GenericType<Token> returnType = new GenericType<Token>()
    {
    };
    return apiClient.invokeAPI(path, "POST", queryParams, postBody, headerParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames, returnType);
}
```

The return type will be Json

Comment: Please open a ticket via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues with the spec to reproduce the issue.